# Using CGContextShowTextAtPoint, how to do Left and Right text Justification?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am doing subclassing of UIView, how do I do Left and Right text justification using CGContextShowTextAtPoint?   thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to measure your text using one of `[NSString sizeWithFont...]` methods. You'll get `size` Use it's `width` to place your text in the right point:

*pseudocode*:

```
if (justification == Left) {
    //just use CGContextShowTextAtPoint
} else {
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:....];
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, self.bounds.width - size.width,....);
}
```