# Putting text over UIImage and text is blurry?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11739047/2547463) answer to put text over my `UIImage` (method 2).  The problem is, the text comes out incredibly blurry, and also is not horizontally and vertically centered.  Here is a screenshot of the behavior:

[image: screen]

How could I fix this?

My code to add the text in is this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    NSString *metaScore =  _getString([[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"metaScore"]);
    NSString *title = _getString([[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]);
    NSString *releaseDate =  _getString([[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"releaseDate"]);
    NSString *type =  _getString([[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"type"]);
    NSString *rating =  _getString([[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"rating"]);

    [cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    cell.textLabel.text = title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@", releaseDate, type, rating];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);

    imageView.image = [self addText:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"] text:metaScore];
    cell.image = imageView.image;

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}

-(UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text1{
    int w = img.size.width;
    int h = img.size.height;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);

    char* text= (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 20, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 256, 256, 256, 1);
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 20, 20, text, strlen(text));
    CGImageRef imgCombined = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    UIImage *retImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgCombined];
    CGImageRelease(imgCombined);

    return retImage;
}
```

Comment: You have to do the math for Horizontal/Vertical scrolling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637682/using-cgcontextshowtextatpoint-how-to-do-left-and-right-text-justification

Comment: That image looks low resolution itself, that looks like as good as the text could be at that resolution... Render it on a bigger image?

Comment: because probably the text width and/or height is an odd number and probably the center-point would be rather fraction pixels than whole ones...

Comment: That answer is a little ambiguous.  Could you post some real code?

Comment: The image has to be 50px by 50px.  I'm rendering it on a uitableviewcell.

Comment: @Witch-King, that is just a comment, not an answer. anyway, the width/height of the text could be odd number (e.g. 49px), and when you just divided by 2 (for finding the center-point) you will get a fraction pixel (24.5px), which is a valid value, it won't be rounded to any whole, the `CoreGraphics` is just 'playing' with the alpha channel to make the text anti-aliased. that is why you get that result.

Comment: @Witch-King why not just use a UILabel if its on a cell? (one is already on the cell if you want)

Comment: Really? There's a label on the cell?

Comment: Post your code that positions and places this text on the UIImage, that'll make it easier for everyone involved.

Comment: Did it.  Check my update.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible you're not drawing your text on pixel-aligned boundaries.

For example, if you position your text at `x:12.4, y:18.7`, then the text won't render crisp, as they're not aligned to the pixels on screen. For a standard display, you need positions and sizes to be whole numbers (they can't be fractions). For retina displays, you can get away by having half points, but it's usually easier to keep them as whole numbers too.

If you're using `CGRect` to determine the position of the text, you can use `CGRectIntegral()` to align them for you. This will floor the positions, and ceiling the sizes. For example:

```
CGRect position = CGRectMake(12.2, 17.8, 44.7, 49.2);
position = CGRectIntegral(position);
/* Position is now
   x: 12, y: 17
   w: 45, h: 50
*/
```

If you're doing it without a CGRect, you can use `floor/floorf` and `ceil/ceilf` (using the `f` variant if you're using `CGFloats`)

**Edit:** Remember CoreGraphics works with pixels and not points, as such you need to take into account the scale factor in any of your calculations. Thankfully, CoreGraphics makes that a bit easier than you'd think. Simply insert this **straight after** you've created your context. This will set the correct scale for any future calculations within that context.

```
CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
CGContextScaleCTM(context, scale, scale);
```

As for the alignment of text, this won't be easy. You're manually setting it to (20,20), which will set the position of the top left corner of the first character. This is unlikely to center your text. As you don't know the rendered width and height of the text though, you can't compensate for the position of the top left corner to make the text centered. You'll struggle here, but once you can find out the rendered width and height of the text, you can calculate the correct position using this and the width/height of the image.

Comment: Using your code sample, this is the resulting UIImage I have: http://i.imgur.com/gMnrhiZ.png

But when viewed on a retina device, you get the blurriness. To remedy this, you need to take into account the screen's scale factor. I'll update my answer.

Comment: So I put this right after `CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);`? It's still blurry.